# general topology subbase of factor spaces

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

Let $\prod_iX_i$ be equipped with the product topology. Suppose each $X_i$ has sub basis $\S_i$.

Show that $S=\{ \pi_i^{-1}(S_i) : S_i\in \S_i \forall i \}$ is a subbasis for $\prod_iX_i$.

My attempt:

It suffices to show that the topology generated by $S$ is $\prod_iX_i$.

The topology is generated by the basis $\{$ $\bigcap_{j=1}^n: \pi_{i_j}^{-1}(S_{i_j})$ $:$ $S_{i_j}\in \S_{i_j} \forall i_j \}$

Let $U$ be open in $\prod_iX_i$. Let $x\in U$. So, there exists basis member $x\in \bigcap_{j=1}^n\ \pi_{i_j}^{-1}(U_{i_j})\subseteq U$.

Now, $U_{i_j}$, being open in $X_{i_j}$ means that $U_{i_j}=\bigcup_{m\in I}\bigcap_{k=1}^m(S_{i_k})$.

But, I'm not sure if all this is correct so far. May I have help?

  -

---

```
                                  **EDIT**
```

Okay, to make things less complicated. Observe the lemma:

***Lemma:*** Let $\prod_iX_i$ be a space equipped with the product topology. Suppose each $X_i$ is a topological space with basis $\mathbb{B}_i$.

Put $\mathbb{B}$ $=$ $\{$ $\bigcap_{j=1}^{n}\pi_{i_j}^{-1}(B_{i_j})$ $:$ $B_{i_j}\in \mathbb{B}_{i_j}$, $n\in \mathbb{N}$, $i_j\in I$ $\}$.

Then $\mathbb{B}$ is a basis for $\prod_i X_i$.

Now, I will use the above lemma to answer the original problem.

It suffices to show that $\mathbb{B}$ is the basis generated by $S$. i.e.

I must show that $\mathbb{B}= \{$ $\bigcap_{j=1}^n \pi_{i_j}^{-1}(S_{i_j})$ $:$ $S_{i_j}\in \S_{i_j} \forall i_j \}$.

Since each $S_{i_j}\in \mathbb{B_{i_j}}$, we get the reverse inclusion.

Observe, given a basis element $B\in \mathbb{B}_i$, $B= \bigcap_{j=1}^nS_j$ where $S_j\in \S_i$ . Hence, $\bigcap_{j=1}^n\pi_{i_j}^{-1}(B_{i_j})$ $=$ $\bigcap_{k=1}^p \pi_{k}^{-1}(S_k)$.

Comment: Have you already proved the corresponding result for bases of the factor spaces?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott corresponding result?

Comment: That if $\mathscr{B}_i$ is a base for the topology on $X_i$ for each $i\in I$, then $\bigcup_{i\in I}\{\pi_i^{-1}[B]:B\in\mathscr{B}_i\}$ is a subbase for the product topology.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott do you mean is a base?

Comment: my problem would be an immediate corollary, wouldn't it?

Comment: No, I do mean a subbase: just look at what happens in $\Bbb R^2$, for instance. But yes, this problem would be an immediate corollary, since the inverse image of an intersection is the intersection of the inverse images.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott could you write a proof for the corresponding theorem, please?

Comment: The one for bases?

Comment: @Brian M.Scott Yup

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I think I figured it out. I will write my answer right now.

Comment: Okay; I was working on the writeup that you requested but having a lot of interruptions, so for now I’ll hold off until I can take a look at what you come up with.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I wrote my answer. By the way, thank you for your help. I appreciate it,

Comment: You’re welcome. And yes, that will work, though writing it up really carefully is a little tricky: for each $B_{i_j}$ you actually have some finite family $\mathscr{F}_{i_j}\subseteq\mathscr{S}_{i_j}$ such that $B_{i_j}=\bigcap\mathscr{F}_{i_j}$, so that $$\bigcap_{j=1}^n\pi_{i_j}^{-1}[B_{i_j}]=\bigcap_{j=1}^n\bigcap_{S\in\mathscr{F}_{i_j}}\pi_{i_j}^{-1}[S]\;,$$ which is still the intersection of finitely many members of $\mathscr{S}$.

Comment: Yeah, I just thought it would be nicer to index the sets by $k$, seemed more convenient haha. But I also noticed a mistake with the way I wrote it, I assumed both unions had $n$ at the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid using or mentioning bases completely: I use the definition that $\mathcal{S}_i$ is a subbase for $(X_i, \mathcal{T}_i)$ iff $\mathcal{T}_i$ is the *smallest* topology that contains $\mathcal{S}_i$. And the definition for the product topology $\mathcal{T}_p$ on $X=\prod_{i \in I} (X_i, \mathcal{T}_i)$ is the *smallest* topology that makes all projections $\pi_i: X \to X_i$ continuous. It's this combination of minimality that will tell us that $\mathcal{T}_p$ is the smallest topology that contains $$\mathcal{S} = \{\pi_i^{-1}[S]: i \in I, S \in \mathcal{S}_i\}$$ which thus means that $\mathcal{S}$ is a subbase for $\mathcal{T}_p$. We will also need the standard fact that for any space $(Z,\mathcal{T})$ a function $f: (Z, \mathcal{T}) \to (X_i, \mathcal{T}_i)$ is continuous iff $$\forall S \in \mathcal{S}_i: f^{-1}[S] \in \mathcal{T}$$ so we can "test" continuity on subbases.

**Main proof**:

Suppose that $\mathcal{T}$ is a topology on $X$ that contains $\mathcal{S}$. For any $i$, and any $S \in \mathcal{S}_i$, $\pi_i^{-1}[S]\in \mathcal{S} \subseteq \mathcal{T}$ so the criterion for continuity from above tells us that $\pi_i$ is continuous. As this holds for all $\pi_i$, all $\pi_i$ are continuous, and by the above definition of the product topology $\mathcal{T}_p \subseteq \mathcal{T}$.
It follows (As this holds for *all* such $\mathcal{T}$) that if $\mathcal{T}(\mathcal{S})$ is the minimal topology that contains $\mathcal{S}$, then $\mathcal{T}_p \subseteq \mathcal{T}(\mathcal{S})$

On the other hand, $\mathcal{T}_p$ is a topology that makes all $\pi$ continuous, and as all $\mathcal{S}_i \subseteq \mathcal{T}_i$, it follows immediately that $\mathcal{S} \subseteq \mathcal{T}_p$ and so $\mathcal{T}_p$ is *some* topology that contains $\mathcal{S}$ and so $\mathcal{T}(\mathcal{S}) \subseteq \mathcal{T}_p$ by minimality again. So we have two inclusions and

$$\mathcal{T}(\mathcal{S}) = \mathcal{T}_p$$ which exactly says that te product topology has $\mathcal{S}$ as a subbase.